# Access VBA to Close a Chrome window opened via Shell

Tags: shell, google-chrome, ms-access, vba

I am attempting to close a `shell` `Chrome` window via a VBA function. My function runs a URL query that returns a `.csv` file. The thing is I would like to close the window so that it is not always showing (This process runs every 3 minutes). I haven't been able to find a solution that I can get to work as of yet. I tried adding `SendKeys "%{F4}"` after as one site suggested. This merely minimizes the window, not close it. I also attempted to try adding `DoCmd.Close Shell, "Untitled"` after, yet this also did not work. I have spent several hours attempting to do, what I imagine is a simple task, and felt another set of eyes could point me in the right direction. Below is my code that opens `Chrome`. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function RunYahooAPI()

Dim chromePath As String

chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""

Shell (chromePath & " -url http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CVX%2CXOM%2CHP%2CSLB%2CPBA%2CATR%2CECL%2CNVZMY%2CMON&f=nsl1op&e=.csv")

End Function
```

Comment: i cant look properly at the minute, but maybe if you set the shell to be an object, poss Chrome? so set x=shell.... or there are some articles on here to close windows tasks, eg when excel hangs or something like that, similar to task manager.

Comment: I thought `SendKeys "^{F4}"` would work. Ends up it does not.

Comment: You could possibily do that in VB Script look at using VB Script for sendkeys.

Answer (score 0):

this VBA code will launch (as in your question) chrome, save the Process handle in the variable `pHandle`, loop all processes with this Handle and then stop the process (after checking user and domain of the process owner) .

```
Sub LaunchandStopProcess()

'
' As in your Question
'
Dim chromePath As String
Dim pHandle As Variant

chromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

'
' Note: Shell pass the Process Handle to the PID variable
'
PHandle = Shell(chromePath & " -url http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CVX%2CXOM%2CHP%2CSLB%2CPBA%2CATR%2CECL%2CNVZMY%2CMON&f=nsl1op&e=.csv")

Dim objWMIcimv2 As Object
Dim objProcess As Object
Dim objList As Object
Dim ProcToTerminate As String
Dim intError As Integer

Set objWMIcimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where Handle='" & CStr(pHandle) & "'")

'
' ObjList contains the list of all process matching the Handle (normally your chrome App, if running)
'

If objList.Count = 0 Then
    ' No matching Process
    ' Set all objects to nothing
    Set objWMIcimv2 = Nothing
    Set objList = Nothing
    Set objProcess = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Else
    '
    ' Parse all matching Processes
    '
    For Each objProcess In objList
        ' additionally check with actual user
        colProperties = objProcess.getowner(strNameofUser, strUserdomain)

        If strUserdomain + "\" + strNameofUser = Environ$("userdomain") + "\" + Environ$("username") Then
            intError = objProcess.Terminate
            If intError <> 0 Then
                '
                ' Trap Error or do nothing if code run unattended
                '
            Else
                ' Confirm that process is killed or nothing if code run unattended
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set objWMIcimv2 = Nothing
    Set objList = Nothing
    Set objProcess = Nothing

End If 
End Sub
```